# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)

Tags: java, android, animation, out-of-memory

I am trying to perform an animation on a button click.. the steps are as follows 
on button click..

1. the button image changes
2. an animation plays
3. next layout is displayed..

But am getting an out of memory exception..

When the animation file was not added to the project there was no error. But since the addition of the anime there is the problem.

I am using 3 class files here(home_screen, button_anime and home)

home_screen.java receives the button click information, changes the button image and transfers to button_anime class the animation file is initiated in the button_anime.java and after anime plays next layout is displayed from home.java

The log cat is as follows..

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:282)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2092)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:15303)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at com.quinoid.thomasinternational.Button_Anime.onCreate(Button_Anime.java:19)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1255):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My home_screen.java

```
home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { <-- error happens somewhere here

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.home1);
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),b); 
        home.setBackgroundDrawable(d); <-- this dose not work..
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Home_Screen.this, Button_Anime.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

Comment: You're out of memory.  It may be the bitmap is too big, it may be that you have a leak elsewhere.  You need to look at your memory use in a heap profiler to tell what's going on.

Comment: all my images are btw 30kb and 50kb.. so how do i check my heap rofiler?? @GabeSechan

Comment: THere's one built into eclipse.  You should look for runaway numbers of some class or large allocations that don't make sense.

Comment: use android:largeheap="true" in manifest file and use the resize images before your took in to your app.this out of memory exception cause for your app takes run at large heap.

Comment: done both.. no use.. @prakash

Comment: @GabeSechan is there a plugin for eclipse ?? heap profiler?? what is the name??

Comment: @user3214173 don't use large heap unless you really need one.

Comment: @user3214173 you can use Memory Analyzer Tool for eclipse. DO osme profiling

Comment: @Raghunandan i got the heap pls check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155628/out-of-memory-exception-analyzing-hprof-file-dump

Answer (score 5):

_img is your imageview. you have to decode your image and set its size like below i am doing.

```
 File imgFile = new File(_path); // path of your file
    if (imgFile.exists()) {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imgFile);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 8;
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inScaled = true;
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null,options);
       _img.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Comment: Voted up. This seems to revolve my issue, but I think there is still a memory leak

Comment: Very goood.  keep it up

Answer (score 0):

You should use `decodeResource(Resources res, int id, BitmapFactory.Options opts)`, and specify the `inSampleSize` -

> If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original
>   image, returning a smaller image to save memory.

Comment: where should i use this??  can u provide an example? also the SampleSize value is it size in kb?? or dimentions?? @yushulx

Comment: Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.home1, opts);For example, inSampleSize == 4 returns an image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original, and 1/16 the number of pixels.